# Нужно, чтобы бот запрашивал контакт у пользователя и пересылал в отдельный чат (aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Имеется машина состояний, каждый стейт в ней - ответ на определенный вопрос.
В конце все ответы автоматически пересылаются в отдельный чат, только загвоздка в том, что в конце я запрашиваю контакт у пользователя, а переслать вместе с другими ответами не знаю как

Comment: так добавьте запрос контакта в машину состояний.

Comment: Взять из Contact type только то что вам нужно, например номер aiogram.types.contact.Contact.phone_number

Comment: @Kuchizu А если не номер нужно переслать, а Имя пользователя, то как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

> А если не номер нужно переслать, а Имя пользователя, то как можно
> реализовать?

```
aiogram.types.contact.Contact.full_name
```

Другие методы:

```
print(dir(aiogram.types.contact.Contact))
```

Comment: А как сначала запросить контакт, а затем переслать в другой чат?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, например:

```
a = print(dir(aiogram.types.contact.Contact))
```

Затем:

```
bot.send_message(айди пользователя/чата , a)
```

А имя пользователя:

```
bot.send_message(айди пользователя/чата , "Тег пользователя:" + message.from_user.username)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]